# How to get permissions to extract post from public Facebook pages?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am finishing my thesis dissertation and I need to retrieve comments from public Facebook pages, but right now I don't have permission to do that.

Does anyone know a way to get this information without have the permission from every public page?

Thank you very much for the help ;)
Marta Eliseu

Answer (score 1):

You must enter the [Facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) portal, register an application (and fill out all the required information), then apply for "[Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS)."

The *Page Public Content Access* permission will allow you to extract information from public facebook pages. Note that it does not allow you to create, edit, or delete posts—it only permits you to *read* posts and comments.

If you have any questions, the [Developer Support](https://developers.facebook.com/support/) page is very helpful. Also, be sure to read the [Facebook Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) to make sure you are not breaking any rules.

**NOTE**: You won't be able to access real data until your app gets approved, but you can create your own test Page while you are developing  your app. See: [App Review](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/).

Comment: Thank you very much for a fast reponse!
To have acess to this feature i need to have a business verification, but i don't have one, how can i do the rest of the steps witout this? There are some workaround?
Thank very much.

Comment: Hmm you're correct, it looks like you need to go through the Business Verification process to get _Page Public Content Access_ now. This goes beyond my knowledge, so hopefully someone else can answer that part of the question.